# use check_box_tag in facet instead of link_to sunspot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, solr, sunspot

I'm using sunspot for search , and i have implemented a fecet search for company this is my view for facet

```
<% for row in @search.facet(:company_id).rows %>
  <li>
    <% if params[:company_id].blank? %>
      <%= link_to row.instance.name, :company_id => row.value %> <%= row.count %>
    <% else %>
      <strong><%= row.instance.name %></strong> (<%= link_to "remove", :month => nil %>)
    <% end %>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

but instead of using link_to i want to use check_box_tag, i have tried something like this but it didn't work `<%= check_box_tag row.instance.name, :company_id => row.value %> <%= row.count %>`